# Laravel redirect after ajax request. (Method not allowed)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have this strange issue. I've a web application in Vue 3 with Inertia, incorporating forms. When I open two browsers and log out in one, then trigger an Ajax request in the other, it reaches the middleware. This is as I would expect, but with the middleware I've written:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ProtectAjaxCalls
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response) $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if ($request->ajax() && !auth()->user()) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
            // dd($request);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It redirects to the login page. Again, that's what I would expect. What I don't understand is that if the Ajax call is a patch request, the redirect also becomes a patch request, which fails, of course. What is happening here, and how can I properly redirect the invalid patch request to a valid get request to the login page?

One solution that I could use is to return a 403 and then execute:

```js
window.location.href = "/login"
```

Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I my case i had to do:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ProtectAjaxCalls
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response) $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if ($request->ajax() && !auth()->user()) {
            return Inertia::location('/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

saves me a lot of code in my views